# aurelia databinding breaks?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, aurelia

Using the Aurelia network it seems databinding silently modifies the data to a `data.toString()`?

Say I have a minimal class (simpleFieldModel.js):

```
export class SimpleFieldModel {
    the_data() {
        return "eeew";
    }
}
```

The main view looks like (app.html & app.js):

```
<template>
    <require from="./field"></require>
    <field field=${field}></field>
</template>
```

-

```
import {SimpleFieldModel} from './SimpleFieldModel';

export class App {
    constructor() {
        this.field  = new SimpleFieldModel();
        let n = this.field.the_data();
    }
}
```

The custom html element looks like (field.html & field.ts):

```
<template>
    ${fieldName}
</template>
```

-

```
import {bindable, bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {FieldModel} from "./FieldModel";
import {SimpleFieldModel} from "./SimpleFieldModel";

export class Field {
    @bindable({defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.OneTime}) field: SimpleFieldModel = undefined;

    secretMessage = 'Be sure to drink your Ovaltine!';

    constructor() {
    }

    get fieldName(): string {
        if (this.field !== undefined) {
            let fm = new SimpleFieldModel();
            alert(fm.the_data());
            alert(this.field.the_data())
            return this.field.the_data();
        } else {
            return "undefined";
        }
    }
}
```

Now above "crashes" after the first alert. - And using webstorm's debugger shows me that "the_data is undefined". - Further analysis shows that `this.field` is actually a string, just the string respresentation of the actual field. - So how would I "chain bind" as in above example? How to make it so that the `field` member inside `Field` class is bound to the `field` member of `app` class?

Answer (score 0):

The binding `<field field=${field}></field>` in your app.html will translate the field value to a string. You should use `<field field.bind='field'></field>` to bind the actual object held in the `field` to the `field` component.